# Iphone contact App open using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I have phonegap application requirement where i want to open iphone default form, so any one knows how to open native application open from phonegap ,i have also try for mail and itunes but it didn't  work at all, i have also follow the below apple document for open native app but not still succeed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mail url schema IOS**

The mailto scheme is used to launch the Mail app and open the email compose sheet. When specifying a mailto URL, you must provide the target email address. The following examples show strings formatted for Safari and for native apps.

```
HTML link:
<a href="mailto:frank@wwdcdemo.example.com">John Frank</a>
Native app URL string:
mailto:frank@wwdcdemo.example.com
```

**Call**

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

[other URL schema follow here][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can launch native or phone gap app from your phonegap application using custom url scheme. Here condition is the app you want to open must be configured for custom url scheme and you should know that url. For example to open facebook app just type fb://profile from your browser. so you can give this url as target on your anchor tag or on click event or whatever way you want.

Comment: Do u have any example

Comment: sorry not now. I implemented it some time back but now I don't have access to that code.

Comment: Here i want to open contact native app in ios phonegap so,do u have any idea how can i open or launch contact and able to make call within application.

Comment: I think for this type of requirement you can use phongap contact plugin. please refer http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find . I think it will give you a proper direction.

Comment: i know about how to add and retrive contact , i want to open iphone contact application .